# Writing two variables in same scanf_s

Tags: c, scanf

So I want to write two variables in the same `scanf_s`. Maybe Im not even using the right names to describe what I want because im new to this but basically I want it to come out as this:

```
What is your last and first name: John Smith
Thank you now I know that your first name is John and your last name is Smith
```

And what I have written is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    char myFirstName[20];
    char myLastName[20];

    printf("\nWhat is your first and last name: ");
    scanf_s("???")
    printf("Thank you now I know that your first name is %s", myFirstName); printf(" and your last name 
    is %s\n",myLastName);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And I dont know how I should write the `scanf_s` part to include the two variables (`myFirstName` and `myLastName`) so it comes out as I want it.

Comment: Can you read *one* string with `scanf_s`? There's no real limit to the number of format specifiers, for either `scanf` (and related functions like `scanf_s`) or `printf`.

Comment: There is no C header `iostream`. Do you compile with C or C++ compiler? Those are different languages.

Comment: [Don't use `scanf` to read interactive input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf); it cannot handle the user typing something other than what you expected. Use `fgets` to read an entire line of whatever the user typed, and then parse it using functions such as `strsep`.  [Don't use `scanf_s`, or any of the other `_s` functions, at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915149/using-c11-standard-with-clang-for-use-of-strcpy-s/57915261); they are not portable and don't solve the problems they were intended to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two inputs won't contain space characters, you can write like this:

```
if (scanf_s("%19s%19s",
    myFirstName, (unsigned)sizeof(myFirstName),
    myLastName, (unsigned)sizeof(myLastName)) != 2) {
    puts("input failed");
    return 1;
}
```

points:

- Yon can specify multiple conversion specifiers in the format string.
- `%19s` is a format spacifier for reading string `"%s"` with a limit to save at most 19 characters plus one terminating NUL character.
- When reading strings or characters via `scanf_s`, buffer size in type `unsigned` must be specified after each pointers to buffers.
- `scanf_s` returns the number of successfully read data, so it should be checked to see if enough data are read.

reference:

[scanf_s, _scanf_s_l, wscanf_s, _wscanf_s_l | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I'm sure you mean `sprintf(fmt, "%%%us%%%us", (unsigned)sizeof (myFirstName) - 1, (unsigned)sizeof (myLastName) - 1); if (scanf(fmt, ...) != 2) ...`

Comment: @pmg The question says "in same `scanf_s`", and unfortunately some compilers dislike `scanf`. [windows - error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe in c programming - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577519/error-c4996-scanf-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-in-c-programming)

Comment: I meant `scanf_s` (sorry). The point is your use of literal `19` versus `sizeof(myFirstName)` ... either use `19` and `20`, or always `sizeof` :)